# What is this noise on my computer

Tags: troubleshooting, fan, noise

I recently have a strange noise coming from my laptop, I believe it's the fan so I opened and cleaned them but the noise remain.
What is weird is that it doesn't always make sound.
I was wondering if it's really the fan or can be something else and if there's something I can do about it.
Check the noise on the video below.

Thanks!

> [Click here to see my video](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/6555e09147f16cbd3210bd34)

Comment: There's a possibility the fan is catching somewhere in its frame. The simplest test for this is stick your finger in it & see if the noise immediately stops. It will be fine held still for just second or two, and they're not powerful enough to hurt. Don't use something hard, you might break the blades.

Comment: @Tetsujin, could be it's hitting an insect -- going back to the origin of "bug" - https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_334663

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - LOL, yup, but the OP said they'd cleaned it. They've have found any bugs;)